# Populate View with 2 Lists (Group by LINQ queries)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new to ASP.net MVC and I have looked at other questions and tried multiple methods to populate a view with 2 IEnumerables using a ViewModel. It seems using the groupby methods in the controller and passing them to the View has created some problems.

The overall problem is that the view doesn't accept ListCatViewModel.  It gives the error:  IEnumerable does not contain a definition for 'Category' and no extension method 'Category' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable

In the multiple questions that I have seen on Stackoverflow and other sources we are supposed to combine the two lists with a variable and then pass that variable to the View.  After that we are supposed to reference the ViewModel.  When I reference the ViewModel I cannot access the properties in each IEnumerable (NotesList and RelList).  I am looking for direction on how to change the controller and/or reference in the View to accept the 2 separate collections to ultimately create two tables.

Summary of Code:  CatViewModel and RelViewModel hold different properties.  ListCatViewModel contains the IEnumerable collections.

```
     public class CatViewModel
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }

        public decimal CountOfLoans { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
        public decimal TotalVolume { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
        public decimal UnfundedCommitment { get; set; }     
    }

 public class RelViewModel
    {
      public string RelationshipName { get; set; }

        public decimal CountOfLoans { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
        public decimal TotalVolume { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
        public decimal UnfundedCommitment { get; set; }
    }



public class ListCatViewModel
    {    
        public IEnumerable<CatViewModel> NotesList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<RelViewModel> RelList { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            ListCatViewModel LCVM = new ListCatViewModel();

            LCVM.NotesList = GetCatList();
            LCVM.RelList = GetRelList();

            return View(LCVM);
        }

        public IEnumerable<CatViewModel> GetCatList()  //Category group by query
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            IEnumerable<CatViewModel> CatVM = db.LoanPortfolio.GroupBy(i => i.Category)


                .Select(g => new CatViewModel
                {
                    Category = g.Key,
                    CountOfLoans = g.Count(),
                    TotalVolume = g.Sum(i => i.Volume),
                    UnfundedCommitment = g.Sum(i => i.Unfunded),
                    //Average = g.Average(i => i.Volume)
                })
             .OrderBy(c => c.Category)

             .AsEnumerable();

            return CatVM;

        }

        public IEnumerable<RelViewModel> GetRelList()


        {

            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            IEnumerable<RelViewModel> RelVM = db.LoanPortfolio.GroupBy(i => i.RelationshipName)




                 .Select(g => new RelViewModel
                 {
                     RelationshipName = g.Key,
                     CountOfLoans = g.Count(),
                     TotalVolume = g.Sum(i => i.Volume),
                     UnfundedCommitment = g.Sum(i => i.Unfunded),
                     //Average = g.Average(i => i.Volume)
                 })
              .OrderBy(c => c.RelationshipName)

              .AsEnumerable();

            return RelVM;
        }
```

View:

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Risk.ViewModel.ListCatViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GroupByLoanPAllowanceB";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Category</h2>




<table class="table">
    <tr>


        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NotesList.Category)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NotesList.CountOfLoans)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NotesList.TotalVolume)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NotesList.UnfundedCommitment)
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>


            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NotesList.Category)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountOfLoans)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalVolume)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnfundedCommitment)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: `@foreach (var item in Model.NotesList)` and `@foreach (var item in Model.RelList)`

Comment: Or create an editor or display template and just use `EditorFor` or `DisplayFor`, respectively.

Comment: How do I add a single iteration of the column names above each foreach block of code?  I need to be able to reference them in each list.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is not `IEnumerable<Risk.ViewModel.ListCatViewModel>`, it is now `ListCatViewModel`

Try:

```
@model Risk.ViewModel.ListCatViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GroupByLoanPAllowanceB";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

And when iterating over the list, you need to access it off the `Model`

```
@foreach (var item in Model.NotesList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountOfLoans)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalVolume)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnfundedCommitment)
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your comments.  They have been helpful.  This works for the data under under Displayfor.  How do I change it for the DisplayNameFor to get the column headings?

Comment: This is the code I put in and it gives me a column heading for each row of data.  How do I change this?    
    @ foreach(var item in Model.NotesList)
    {


    <tr>


        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Category)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're just trying to display the data, create some templates in the `Views -> Shared -> DisplayTemplates` folder (you may need to create it), and then use `DisplayFor`. Here's an example for your CatViewModel:

#### CatViewModel.cshtml

```
@model Your.Fully.Qualified.Namespace.CatViewModel

<tr>
    <td>
        @Model.Category
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.CountOfLoans
    </td>

    <td>
        @Model.TotalVolume
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.UnfundedCommitment
    </td>
</tr>
```

#### Parent view:

```
@model Risk.ViewModel.ListCatViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GroupByLoanPAllowanceB";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Category</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Category
        </th>
        <th>
            Count Of Loans
        </th>

        <th>
            Total Volume
        </th>
        <th>
            Unfunded Commitment
        </th>
    </tr>

    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NotesList)
</table>
```

The Razor engine is smart enough to look for a partial view with the same name as the model (in the aforementioned folder) when you call either `EditorFor` or `DisplayFor`. So, if the property was of type `Foo`, and you had a view called `Foo.cshtml`, it would be used for that property. If you supply a collection, it will also iterate through the collection and generate markup for each item.

There's also [an overload that allows you to specify the template to use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.String%29), if you don't want to follow the convention I mentioned above.